# Datacontract and servicecontract difference

Tags: wcf

As far as I knw -

ServiceContract can be used for interface/class whereas DataContract can b used only for Class, Struct and Enums

Apart from this - what are other differences b/w these 2 ? 
When DataContract and ServiceContract should be used in an application ?

Any sample or link would also do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The **ServiceContract** defines the service's contract - its shape and form. It defines the name of the service, its XML namespace etc., and it's typically an interface (but could also be applied to a class) that contains methods decorated with the `[OperationContract]` attribute - the service methods.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Response GetData(int someKey);
}
```

The **DataContract** is a totally different beast - it decorates a class to define it as a class that's being used as a parameter or return value from one of the service methods. It's labeling that class as a "thing" to serialize onto the wire to transmit it. It's an instruction for the WCF runtime (the data contract serializer) that this class is intended to be used in a WCF service.

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{ 
    [DataMember] 
    int Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    string ProductName { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    DateTime DateOfPurchase { get; set; }
}
```

So the service contract and the data contract are two totally separate parts that play together to make a WCF service work - it's not like one could replace the other or something.

Comment: Well! I regret I'm not a C# developer! C# is awesome! and your explaination is awsome!

Comment: Great explanation! Is there any specific case where you would decorate a class with `[ServiceContract]` or is it recommended to only use it for interfaces?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: if you *have* an interface that defines the service (this is a *recommendation* - not a requirement), then  the `[ServiceContract]` should be only on the interface. The only reason I'd ever set the `[ServiceContract]` on a class is if that class *defines + implements* a service (without a separate interface)